# vuejs - how to capture the value inside the input name?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm using `vue-js-toggle-button` library.

I know I could access the value inside the name using $refs but I have 3 toggle buttons and I cant set Ref because I wanna to get the name value dynamically in "payload"...

In others buttons I used `@click="Myfucntion($event.target)"`

but `$event.target` doesn't work with @change in this library.

```
    <toggle-button
          color="rgba(9, 90, 6, 1)"
          @change="SaveConfigFinalSemana($event)"
          name="email"
          ref='email'
          :labels="{checked: 'Sim', unchecked: 'Não'}"
        />

<toggle-button
          color="rgba(9, 90, 6, 1)"
          @change="SaveConfigFinalSemana($event)"
          name="sms"
          ref='sms'
          :labels="{checked: 'Sim', unchecked: 'Não'}"
        />

<toggle-button
          color="rgba(9, 90, 6, 1)"
          @change="SaveConfigFinalSemana($event)"
          name="wpp"
          ref='wpp'
          :labels="{checked: 'Sim', unchecked: 'Não'}"
        />

 const payload = {
        disparos_fds: elemento.value,
        tipo_envio: this.$refs.wpp.name,
        client_uuid: user.company_uuid
      };
```

Answer (score 1):

Per the documentation for [vue-js-toggle-button events](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-js-toggle-button#events), the event value emitted from a click will be an object containing two properties, `value` and `srcEvent`. `value` is the "state of the object" and `srcEvent` would be the "source click event". `srcEvent` is where you could access `target` if you need. Try the following:

```
<toggle-button
  color="rgba(9, 90, 6, 1)"
  @change="SaveConfigFinalSemana($event)"
  name="email" ref='email'
  :labels="{checked: 'Sim', unchecked: 'Não'}"
/>
```

Here is an example of method/handler SaveConfigFinalSemana logging out the `value` and `srcEvent` properties present on the emitted object:

```
SaveConfigFinalSemana: function($event) {
  console.log($event.value);
  console.log($event.srcEvent);
}
```

If you need the DOM event `target` property and the `name` property of `target`, you could access it like:

```
SaveConfigFinalSemana: function($event) {
  console.log($event.srcEvent.target);
  console.log($event.srcEvent.target.name);
}
```

Here is an [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-aywdyc) in action.

Hopefully that helps!